# Problem with saving value with the input type number to the chosen field to the database by C# in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a problem with implement saving value with input type number to the database. I have created website with ASP .NET MVC with UnitOfWork and Repositories. I have a Commodity model, where I have field Amount, and I have HomeViewModel in which I have a field Amount also. I would like to overwrite the amount field from the commodity model. Should I use onchange or onclick in input or a tags in html code, or all with my basic ideas are nonsens ?
Below is the code snippet with view created in RazorPages with extension .cshtml.

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="row my-3">
        @foreach(var Commodity in Model.CommodityList.Where(c=>c.CategoryId==category.Id))
        {
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-md-6 pb-4">
                 <div class="card" style="border:2px solid #43ac6a;border-radius:5px; 
                    backgroundcolor: #fffeee">
                    <div class="pl-3 pt-1 text-center">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-primary"><b>@Commodity.Name</b></h3>
                    </div>
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                     <div class="pl-1 text-muted">@localizer.Get("Price")</div>
                     <div class="pr-1 text-danger h5">$@Commodity.Price</div>
                 </div>
                 <img src="@Commodity.ImageUrl" class="card-img-top p-2 rounded" />
                 <div class="col-9">
                     <input onchange="save()" asp-for="@Commodity.Amount" type="number" 
                       id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" />
                 </div>
                 <a onclick="save()" asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-success" 
                   style="border- 
                   radius:2px;" asp-route-id="@Commodity.Id" 
                   onclick="save()">@localizer.Get("Details")</a>
                   </div>
              </div>
           }
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I can't write the value from  after pressing the button below as the  tag.

Below is the method written by me in controller regarding to the view

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
      HomeVM = new HomeViewModel()
      {
        CategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll(),
        CommodityList = _unitOfWork.Commodity.GetAll(includeProperties: "Category"),
        ServiceList = _unitOfWork.Service.GetAll(includeProperties: "Category,Payment"),
        EmployeeList = _unitOfWork.Employee.GetAll(includeProperties: "Service"),
        Amount = _unitOfWork.Commodity.GetFirstOrDefault(includeProperties: 
         "Category").Amount
      };

      foreach (var commodity in (_unitOfWork.Commodity.GetAll(includeProperties: 
         "Category")))
      {
        var CommodityFromDb = commodity;
        CommodityFromDb.Amount = HomeVM.Amount;
        _unitOfWork.Save();
      }

      _unitOfWork.Save();

      return View(HomeVM);
    }
```

I have a guess that you probably need to do it somehow with jquery, in a file with the extension js, but I have no idea how. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You mean you want to use save function in js to pass data to action?Which action you want to use?Details?

Comment: I want to save value with input type number using jquery or js so that pass a value to the amount field in the model and save it to the database and be able to overwrite with every change in this input, but all with my ideas are not working.

Comment: Can you share your save() function?